# two-column lstlisting in landscape orientation

Tags: listings, minipage, landscape

How can I divide my page in two to show my code with lstlisting? This is a large code and I want to set as 2 pages in one. Is an appendix of my project not all the document.

**EDIT**

thanks to Bordaigorl I set it to double column but when I add \landscape option this is my result:

[image]

Comment: You could use `\twocolumn` in your appendix to switch to a two column display. In that way you do not need to break your code in minipages manually

Comment: Thanks, how can I set it to landscape because with \landscape it doesnt works properly :/ I attached an image

Comment: Good point. I suggest you have a look at the `geometry` package, I think that handles twocolumns correctly.

Comment: Ok I will take a look

Comment: How do you allow rotated (so technically normal) content on landscape pages ? (comment answer below)
@Bordaigorl: Can you achiev this with geometry? Including geometry package changes the page layout -even without any additional parameters- in a way that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to switch to a two columns layout for the appendix.
Unfortunately the `\twocolumn` macro does not play well with packages to switch to landscape mode mid-document. The `geometry` package solves the problem for whole-document layout but it cannot switch to landscape mid-document.

A solution achieving both two columns and landscape for a section of the document can be obtained using the packages `lscape` (or `pdflscape`) and `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the demo

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}
very long code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you allow rotated (so technically normal) content on landscape pages ? - I'd like to put *chapter (appendix) and section headings* at the top of the page in normal vertical-paper style. Landscape does not allow me to start code on the same page as my chapter heading (modifies next page).

Comment: @hillbilly you could try with `\rotatebox` but for a specific situation I would suggest you post a new question with a MWE